# How to Distinct() List which contains classes that implement interface? C#

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

First of all, I have interfact `ICommand`:

```
public interface ICommand
{
}
```

and concrete classes `ThreadSelectCommand`, `SearchCommand` and so on:

```
public class ThreadSelectCommand : ICommand
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public ThreadSelectCommand()
    {
        Value = 1;
    }
}


public class SearchCommand : ICommand
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public SearchCommand()
    {
        Value = "";
    }
}
```

`List<ICommand> resultCommands` can contains a few of each command, and I need to `Distinct()` this list. How to do this?
I know, that I should use comparator. But this classes are not the same.

Comment: Of course you can use Distinct.... e.g. `var output = resultCommands.Distinct()`. What is it about that output that you do not want?

Comment: @JohnWu I need that `resultCommands` contains only one `SearchCommand` and only one `ThreadSelectCommand`

Comment: MoreLinq's `DistinctBy` is an option to consider in the future.

Comment: Why did you delete your task naming question?

Comment: @Enigmativity - question close. I don't need use Name, CurrentID is decision.

Comment: @GregorySysoev - It was still a good question. You could have left it for others.

Comment: @Enigmativity ok, in another situation I will not delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements you want (only one instance per concrete type) can be done by comparing the runtime types of the elements in the list.

```
public class  CommandTypeComparer : EqualityComparer<ICommand> 
{
    public override bool Equals(ICommand x, ICommand y)
    {
        return Type.Equals(x.GetType(), y.GetType());
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(ICommand x)
    {
        return x.GetType().GetHashCode()
    }
}
```

You would then use it like `resultCommands.Distinct(new CommandTypeComparer());`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. But what is the relation between the two methods: `Equals` and `GetHashCode`? I'm just study.

Comment: Read up the documentation of IEqualityComparer, it has a explination https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a following list of object as your sample above

```
List<ICommand> resultCommands = new List<ICommand> {
    new ThreadSelectCommand(),
    new ThreadSelectCommand(),
    new ThreadSelectCommand(),
    new SearchCommand(),
    new SearchCommand(),
};  


var groups = resultCommands.GroupBy(x => x.GetType());

var distinctList = groups.Select(g => { 
    if(g.Key == typeof(ThreadSelectCommand))
    {
        return g.Select(x => (ThreadSelectCommand)x).GroupBy(x => new { x.Value }).Select(x => (ICommand)x.First()).First();
    }
    else if(g.Key == typeof(SearchCommand))
    {
        return g.Select(x => (SearchCommand)x).GroupBy(x => new { x.Value }).Select(x => (ICommand)x.First()).First();
    }
    else 
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    }).ToList();
```

The distinctList will contain 2 elements